# Why does c# only validate some of my fields which are required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have these models:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid VisitingTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
public class Patient
{
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

And this my controller:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SchedulerController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("book-appointment")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> BookAppointmentAsync([FromBody] Appointment appointment)
        {
           //some logic
        }
}
```

Why does this call work:

```json
{
    "UserId": "c6c988dc-04d7-40dd-a36b-dacd70adf617",
    "Patient": {
        "Mail": "as.asd@das.ch",
        "UserId": "c6c988dc-04d7-40dd-a36b-dacd70adf617",
        "Lastname": "asd",
        "Firstname": "asd"
    }
}
```

If I remove the userid I'll get the message that userid is required why this isn't the case for Duration for example?

Comment: Can you show how you know that "it works"? Because that JSON is invalid according to the Data Attributes in place

Comment: I did a call in Postman and I was able to go in to the methode body.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. But did you check the `ModelState.IsValid` property? I'm sure that it'll be `false`

Comment: Yes I checked it and it is true

Comment: @Severin.Hersche All the required fields are being validated. All the value types have been satisfied as provided because they all have non-null default values. If you were to make then nullable types, then you will get the expected behavior.

Comment: @Severin.Hersche I added a link to the documentation. Check it out to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the required fields are being validated. All the value types have been satisfied as provided because they all have non-null default values and you provided a `UserId`

When the class is initialized by the model binder those value types will all have non-null values and will satisfy the `[Required]` validation attribute.

If you were to make them nullable types,

```
[Required]
public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
[Required]
public string UserId { get; set; }
[Required]
public int? Duration { get; set; }
[Required]
public Guid? VisitingTypeId { get; set; }
[Required]
public int? Status { get; set; }
[Required]
public Patient Patient { get; set; }
```

then you will get the expected behavior for the JSON shown in your example

Reference [Model validation in ASP.NET Core: [Required] validation on the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#required-validation-on-the-server)